# Power BI order linechart by MonthName on X-Axis and RunningMonth in Tooltip

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

In my datamodel I have sales over years in different SalesEvents.
I need to compare the sales Quantity (Y-Axis) for multipe EventNames (Legend) over Monthnames (X-Axis).
If I use the RunningMonth that would be months from first order on each EventName the visula works.

[image]

But I need to build the visual to show the MonthName ordered by RunningMonth since a SalesEvent can go longer then one year. This does however not work, since the order by Tooltip failes due to the automatic Sum:

[image]

I have tried a measure for sorting in the Tooltip like I have found on other poasts but due to my multiple EventNames it seams not to be working:

```
Sorter = 
SWITCH( VALUES(Orders[SortABC]),
"1",1,
"2",2,
"3",3,
"4",4,
"5",5,
"6",6,
"7",7,
"8",8,
"9",9,
"10",10,
"11",11,
"12",12,
"13",13,
"14",14,
"15",15,
"16",16,
17
)
```

Here is the example data if anyone can help me.

```
with upa as
(
select 'Sales19' as EventName, 1 as RunningMonth,  cast('28.11.2019' as Date) as CreatedOn, 100 as Quantity union all
select 'Sales19' as EventName, 2 as RunningMonth,  cast('31.12.2019' as Date) as CreatedOn, 200 as Quantity union all
select 'Sales19' as EventName, 3 as RunningMonth,  cast('02.02.2020' as Date) as CreatedOn, 150 as Quantity union all
select 'Sales19' as EventName, 4 as RunningMonth,  cast('06.03.2020' as Date) as CreatedOn, 70 as  Quantity union all
select 'Sales19' as EventName, 5 as RunningMonth,  cast('08.04.2020' as Date) as CreatedOn, 50 as  Quantity union all
select 'Sales19' as EventName, 6 as RunningMonth,  cast('11.05.2020' as Date) as CreatedOn, 40 as  Quantity union all
select 'Sales19' as EventName, 7 as RunningMonth,  cast('13.06.2020' as Date) as CreatedOn, 20 as  Quantity union all
select 'Sales19' as EventName, 8 as RunningMonth,  cast('16.07.2020' as Date) as CreatedOn, 30 as  Quantity union all
select 'Sales19' as EventName, 9 as RunningMonth,  cast('18.08.2020' as Date) as CreatedOn, 8 as   Quantity union all
select 'Sales19' as EventName, 10 as RunningMonth, cast('20.09.2020' as Date) as CreatedOn, -12 as Quantity union all
select 'Sales19' as EventName, 11 as RunningMonth, cast('23.10.2020' as Date) as CreatedOn, -20 as Quantity union all
select 'Sales19' as EventName, 12 as RunningMonth, cast('25.11.2020' as Date) as CreatedOn, 5 as   Quantity union all
select 'Sales19' as EventName, 13 as RunningMonth, cast('28.12.2020' as Date) as CreatedOn, 0 as   Quantity union all
select 'Sales19' as EventName, 14 as RunningMonth, cast('30.01.2021' as Date) as CreatedOn, 0 as   Quantity union all
select 'Sales19' as EventName, 16 as RunningMonth, cast('04.03.2021' as Date) as CreatedOn, -4 as  Quantity union all
select 'Sales23' as EventName, 1 as RunningMonth,  cast('02.12.2023' as Date) as CreatedOn, 125 as Quantity union all
select 'Sales23' as EventName, 2 as RunningMonth,  cast('07.01.2024' as Date) as CreatedOn, 250 as Quantity union all
select 'Sales23' as EventName, 3 as RunningMonth,  cast('12.02.2024' as Date) as CreatedOn, 187 as Quantity union all
select 'Sales23' as EventName, 4 as RunningMonth,  cast('19.03.2024' as Date) as CreatedOn, 87 as  Quantity union all
select 'Sales23' as EventName, 5 as RunningMonth,  cast('24.04.2024' as Date) as CreatedOn, 62 as  Quantity union all
select 'Sales23' as EventName, 6 as RunningMonth,  cast('30.05.2024' as Date) as CreatedOn, 50 as  Quantity union all
select 'Sales23' as EventName, 7 as RunningMonth,  cast('05.07.2024' as Date) as CreatedOn, 25 as  Quantity union all
select 'Sales23' as EventName, 8 as RunningMonth,  cast('10.08.2024' as Date) as CreatedOn, 37 as  Quantity union all
select 'Sales23' as EventName, 9 as RunningMonth,  cast('15.09.2024' as Date) as CreatedOn, 10 as  Quantity union all
select 'Sales23' as EventName, 10 as RunningMonth, cast('21.10.2024' as Date) as CreatedOn, -15 as Quantity union all
select 'Sales23' as EventName, 11 as RunningMonth, cast('26.11.2024' as Date) as CreatedOn, -25 as Quantity union all
select 'Sales23' as EventName, 13 as RunningMonth, cast('01.01.2025' as Date) as CreatedOn, 6 as   Quantity union all
select 'Sales23' as EventName, 14 as RunningMonth, cast('06.02.2025' as Date) as CreatedOn, 0 as   Quantity union all
select 'Sales23' as EventName, 15 as RunningMonth, cast('14.03.2025' as Date) as CreatedOn, 0 as   Quantity
)
select * from upa
```

Please help.

The result should look somthing like this. (The Sales23 line is drawn by me.)
[image]

After putting in Sams ideas and filling the gabs in my DateTable it worked.

Then the last stepp occured, to put it in a RunningTotal. If I adjust my RunningTotal formula I get a flet line. How can I put all this into a running total?

```
Chart Value RT = IF(NOT ISBLANK([Chart Month]), 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Orders[Quantity]),
        FILTER(
            ALL(Orders),
            // Old part of function:
            // Orders[RunningMonth] <= MAX(Orders[RunningMonth])
            // New part of function:
            [Chart Value] <= [Chart Value]
            && Orders[EventName] = max(Orders[EventName]) 
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Not sure if this makes sense, since I assume each event can/will start from a different month, and if running more than a year, you will get the overlapping months summing up. So either keep it as it is, or use the actual date in x-axis.

Comment: Some events can start october some november but all can have a huge impact by december x-Mas sale. If I use the MonthName I can see when the storngest months are. By RunningMonth it is not possible to see this.
To avoid the summing up of months, I wanted to use the RunningMonth in addition to the MonthName as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Measure for the chart tooltip that will be used for sorting.

```
Chart Month = 
  var chartFirstDate = CALCULATE(MIN('Orders'[CreatedOn]), ALLSELECTED('Orders'))
  var chartFirstMonth = MONTH(chartFirstDate)

  var thisFirstDate = CALCULATE(MIN('Orders'[CreatedOn]), ALLEXCEPT('Orders', 'Orders'[EventName]))
  var thisFirstMonth = MONTH(thisFirstDate)
  
  var monthStartDiff = IF(thisFirstMonth < chartFirstMonth, 12, 0) + thisFirstMonth - chartFirstMonth
  var thisMonthDuration = DATEDIFF(thisFirstDate, MIN('Orders'[CreatedOn]), MONTH)

  var result = 1 + thisMonthDuration + monthStartDiff

  return IF(result < 13, result)
```

And create another new Measure for the chart value:

```
Chart Value = IF(NOT ISBLANK([Chart Month]), SUM('Orders'[Quantity]))
```

Use `Chart Value` for your Y-axis, and `Chart Month` for the Tooltips and sort as before.

[image]

For Running Total, you could use:

```
Chart Value RT = 
  var maxD = EOMONTH(MIN('Orders'[CreatedOn]), 0)
  var result =
    CALCULATE(
      [Chart Value],
      ALLEXCEPT('Orders', 'Orders'[EventName]),
      'Orders'[CreatedOn] <= maxD
    )
  return IF(NOT ISBLANK([Chart Month]), result)
```

Comment: With your attempt I was not able to put both Events in to compare. It works fine if I filter on 1 Event only but as soon as I select both all Events start at the same time again.
Do you have an idea how to solve that?

Comment: What do you get when you select two events (share a screengrab). And what would you want to see (share a screengrab mock-up/sketch).

Comment: I have added a skretch of the wanted design.

Comment: I was able to create your mockup back when I gave the answer. Let me recreate it tomorrow and share with you

Comment: See above added image in the answer - this is done with Option 1 using the `RunningMonth txt` measure. Sale23 starts in Dec, but also extends over to Nov, when you hover over the data points, it does show the correct running month.

Comment: Thank you for puting in so mutch effort. The sales23 however only starts in december but in your solution both apear to be starting in november. Is it possible to start the lines in their startingmonth as in my skretch?

Comment: No, simply because Sales23 does have Nov data (RunningMonth = 11). This is what I was referring to in the very first comment to your question. Where/how should this Nov data be plotted?

Comment: Thats why I wanted to sort by RunningMonth so the second Nov goes to the end.
I would also have the possibility to show only the first 9 months since they start at a similar time every year +/- a few weeks. The important data to visualize is the first 9 months then sales dies anyways.

Comment: Updated answer above. This solution will only ever show the first 12 calendar months staring with the earliest event.

Comment: Updated the description. It is sooo close, but somehow january does not want to apply to the lows of time.
And does it make sense to add an filter on the visual for [Chart Month] > 0 ?

Comment: Okay okay - I cheated by adding a Jan value for Sales19. Any reason for the gaps in the data? WIll have to go with plan B and add a separate Month table.

Comment: After applying your cheat there is on last issue. This all does not seam to work for a running total (see description). Where am I wrong?

Comment: Add RT at the bottom of the updated answer above.

Comment: I still have so mutch to learn. Thank you!!